# How can I change variables for the next step in pytest-bdd?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, gherkin, pytest-bdd

I want to change the x from one step to the other, without adding another function

```
Feature: Calculator
    Scenario Outline: simple sum
        Given the x is 1
        And the x is <x>

    Examples:
        | x |
        | 5 |
```

```
from pytest_bdd import given, when, then, scenario, parsers
import logging
info = logging.getLogger('test').info

@scenario("test.feature", "simple sum")
def test_outlined():
    pass

@given(parsers.parse("the x is {x}"))
@given("the x is <x>")
def f(request, x):
    info("x=%s" % x)
```

output:

```
2021-08-31 14:23:30 INFO x=1
2021-08-31 14:23:30 INFO x=1
```

wanted output:

```
2021-08-31 14:23:30 INFO x=1
2021-08-31 14:23:30 INFO x=5
```

thank you so much, please help

Comment: You can use scenario outline tables whenever it is possible. See [this](http://www.datio.com/bbdd/behavior-driver-development-with-python-a-humble-introduction/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to write like this in your feature file

```
Feature: Calculator
Scenario Outline: simple sum
    Given the x is 1
    And the x is 5
    And the x is 9
```

and in your step definition file

```
from pytest_bdd import given, when, then, scenario, parsers
import logging
info = logging.getLogger('test').info

@scenario("test.feature", "simple sum")
def test_outlined():
    pass

@given(parsers.parse("the x is {x}"))
def f(request, x):
    info("x=%s" % x)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but in that way the output is:
2021-10-21 09:23:38 INFO x=<x1>
2021-10-21 09:23:38 INFO x=<x2>
2021-10-21 09:23:38 INFO x=<x3>

I want something more:
2021-10-21 09:23:38 INFO x=1
2021-10-21 09:23:38 INFO x=5
2021-10-21 09:23:38 INFO x=9

Comment: @goncaloandrade I have updated the answer. Please check it